# the number of line in text file Cfile C++

Tags: c++, mfc, cfile

i want to print the number of line printed in C++ by using Cfile.
i want to write the number of line according to the date.
for example in the same file it is written for two days ,

```
Nr   date   time     code     value
1 10/6/2019  09:10   220      55
2 10/6/2019  10:16    33       23
3 10/6/2019  10:50    55       11
1 11/6/2019  03:55    11       15
2 11/6/2019  08:22    18       20
```

everything is right except the line number

```
CString strDate, strYearShort, strTime;

strYearShort = (CString)Datum.year;
strYearShort = strYearShort.Right(2);
strDate = (CString)Datum.day + '.' + (CString)Datum.month + '.' + strYearShort;
strTime = (CString)Zeit.hour + ':' + (CString)Zeit.minute;

buf.Format(_T("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%d\r\n\r\n"), strDate, strTime, (CString)number, (CString)cardnumber, value);

enter code hereif (CTime::GetCurrentTime().GetDay() != lastWriteDay) {
        for (i = 1, i < 100, i++) {
            int Nu = i,
        }
    }
    else if (CTime::GetCurrentTime().GetDay() = lastWriteDay) {
        Nu == 0;
            or (i = 1, i < 100, i++) {
            Nu = i,
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code and the example output don't seem to match. Can you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: it is a small example, the output has more information. my question is how can print the number of line and start from 1 in the next day

Comment: Are you saying that you want a `4` and not a `1` on the last line of the output?

Comment: 1 in the new date, exactly like i wrote

Comment: i spent long time when i was looking in the internet how i can solve this issue. but i have not found anything

Comment: Does the software run constantly and you want to reset the line counter at midnight?

Comment: exactly, this is what i am looking for. this software is working constantly and reset the counter at midnight

Comment: Sounds simple enough. Just keep a variable of the last write time/date. When writing a new line, compare last write time to the current time. If the dates are different, reset the line number.

Comment: Could you please give me an example in MFC ?

Answer (score 0):

Keep a variable of the last write date:

```
// Should be persistent for lifetime of app:
// eg: global, static, or class member
int lastWriteDay = 0;
```

When writing a new line, compare last write date to the current date. If the dates are different, reset the line number.

```
....
if (CTime::GetCurrentTime().GetDay() != lastWriteDay) {
    number = 1;
    lastWriteDay = CTime::GetCurrentTime().GetDay();
}
// Do write....
....
```

Then you can update the number when you create the string:

```
buf.Format(_T("%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\t%s\t%d\r\n\r\n"),
    strDate,
    strTime,
    number++,    // Increment for next time
    cardnumber,
    value);
```

Also, the example in your question does not have enough parameters. And it seems unnecessary to convert the integers to `CString`. Just use the `%d` format specifier.

TODO: You might want to add some code that runs on startup that opens the file, reads the last line and parses the line to get the last write day. Then initialize `lastWriteDay` to that. This is needed for when the app has quit and restarted on the same day for some reason.

Comment: if (CTime::GetCurrentTime().GetDay() != lastWriteDay) {
 for (i = 1, i < 100, i++) {
  int number = i,
 }
}
else if (CTime::GetCurrentTime().GetDay() = lastWriteDay) {
number =0
or (i = 1, i < 100, i++) {
  number = i,
}
} i want to try this code but i could not check the result now could i take your opinon if this code is right in general @Johnny Mopp

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing with the loops. Just add my code to right before the code where you call `buf.Format(....`

Comment: Hallo again, today i tried this code with the machine. number does not increased it gave me 1 in each time. i have tired several times but is not working

Comment: Could you help me please

Comment: this is the code i have used, the only value for n is 1

Comment: @abd.ch `if (Datum.day != lastWriteDay) { n = 1; lastWriteDay = Datum.day; }`

Comment: after i tried this new code, the result is not changed it gave just number 2 , 2 the number is not 1 , 2 @Johnny Mopp